# How do I get my Logitech c510 camera to work?

Tags: 11.10, webcam, logitech

I'm new to Ubuntu and am still learning (recent Windows convert).  How do I get my Logitech HD c510 to work with my Ubuntu 11.10?
Thanks!

Comment: It would help to know what doesn't work. How you determined that something doesn't work. Edit your question to include this information and any error or warning messages you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

It should just work. I have a C910 and it works properly with Skype and Google Chat. A good way to test the camera would be to download [Cheese](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cheese) from the Ubuntu Software Center.